# Why does it receive only 1 integer?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, comma-operator

Why does this receive only one integer? 
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int num1,num2,num3;
    std::cin>>num1,num2,num3;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read about comma operator. You want `std::cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3`.

Comment: Because that's what you asked for.`std::cin>>num1>>num2>>num3;`

Comment: By the way, compiling with `-Wall` would warn about things like this.

Comment: What this comma means so? and what does it do with num2,num3?

Comment: Again, look up 'comma operator'.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can you recommend me a good book as a beginner?

Comment: A lot of books don't cover the comma operator. It's seldom used and often considered a design mistake of the language.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I don't need a book which covers commas, I need a book which builds me as a beginner.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3309790)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) has lower precedence than `operator>>`, so `std::cin>>num1,num2,num3;` is same as `(std::cin>>num1), num2, num3;`; the following `num2, num3` does nothing in fact. (More precisely, `std::cin>>num1` is evaluated firstly and its result is discarded; then `num2` is evaluated, `num3` is evaluated at last and its value is the result of the whole comma expression.)

What you want should be `std::cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;`.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct syntax. That's an application of the comma operator. You want

```
std::cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
```